# Joint probability for discrete and dependent variables

Tags: probability

Given $\bar{X} \sim N(\bar{\mu}, \sigma)$ is a vector of independent continuous random variables (with identical variance) and $Y_j = ( \bar w_{j} \cdot \bar X + b_j > 0)$ is a set of dependent discrete random variables is there a nice expression for the joint probability $P(Y_0 = 1, Y_1 = 1)$?

Also, I think the marginal distributions are given by:

$P(Y_j=1) = \int^{\infty}_{0} N(\bar w_j \cdot \bar \mu + b_j, \sigma) dx = 0.5 - 0.5 erf \left ( -{\bar w_j \cdot \bar \mu + b_j \over \sigma \sqrt {2}} \right )$

Is this correct?

Comment: It might help to clarify your question.  I do not know what that notation means (why is there a greater than sign in the parentheses? I have never seen such a thing)  Or what the sizes of things are, or what $b_j$ is, etc.  And I would expect $Y_j$ to represent a random variable, or a random vector, I do not understand why it is a set.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the notation, I'm not a mathematician by trade. The greater than sign is exactly that, the $Y_j$ are binary random variables describing whether the point $X$ is on the positive side of the hyper-plane $(\bar w_j, b_j)$. I probably shouldn't have used the word "set". I'm using a bar above the variables to identify it as a vector. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Wow, I would never have known that $Y_j$ values were supposed to be binary variables.

Comment: Define $R_j = \sum_{k=1}^K w_{jk}X_k + b_j$, then $R_j$ is Gaussian with mean $\sum_{k=1}^K w_{jk} \mu_k + b_j$ and variance $\sum_{k=1}^K w_{jk}^2\sigma^2$.  Then you can define: $$Y_j = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \mbox{if $R_j>0$}\\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$ and $Pr[Y_j=1]$ is an integral of the PDF of $R_j$ over $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Then $(R_0, R_1)$ is _jointly Gaussian_, you find the covariance matrix, and then $Pr[(Y_0=1, Y_1=1)]$ is an integral $\int_{r_0=0}^{\infty}\int_{r_1=0}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Bingo. And to add to Michael's comment, to find the covariance between any two $R_j$, you may find [this question useful](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125422/correlation-between-two-linear-sums-of-random-variables).